# Не подключается slick- карусель в битрикс 1с

Tags: битрикс, slick.js

Хочу подключить slick- карусель, Но выходит следующая ошибка:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://krupenko-improvements.com/book/?clear_cache=Y' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Подключаю через cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Просто добавьте `s` после `http` в `src` подключения слик слайдера. В ошибке же написано что не так.

Comment: А ещё лучше просто переходите по ссылке, из src, копируете всё, создаёте фаил slick.min.js и вставляете в него код со страницы. Потом локально подключаете. Точно также с jquery можете сделать

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи Тогда уже лучше установить npm пакет, сейчас не начало 2000-х, чтобы вендоры руками по папочкам раскладывать)

Comment: @Simon насколько я знаю в Битриксе работают уже с готовой вёрсткой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер выдаёт ошибку что текущий сайт работает по HTTPS, а вы пытаетесь загрузить данные по HTTP. Достаточно просто поменять адрес загрузки.